# How to insert data MySQL using PHP + Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

There are a lot of similar questions out there, but my issue is a little bit more complicated.

I have a table called `movies` from which I am displaying data in a loop using the code below:

```
<?php 
// LISTS MOVIES ORDERED BY RELEASE DATE -- LATEST MOVIES BY YEAR.
$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT id, title, releaseDate, posterUrl FROM movies ORDER BY releaseDate DESC LIMIT 4");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($movieId, $movieTitle, $movieDate, $moviePoster);
while ($stmt->fetch()) { ?>
    <div class="index-movie">
        <div class="meta-container">
            <img src="<?php echo $moviePoster; ?>" alt="<?php echo $movieTitle; ?>" class="poster">
            <div class="meta">
                <span class="title"><?php echo $movieTitle . ' (' . substr($movieDate, 0, 4) . ')'; ?></span>                       
            </div>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" class="watchlist-form">
            <input type="text" name="watchlist-movie-id" style="display: none;" class="watchlist-movie-id" value="<?php echo $movieId; ?>">
            <input type="submit" class="add-to-watchlist" value="Add to Watchlist" name="add-to-watchlist">
        </form>
    </div>
<?php 
}
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
?>
```

This loop displays four entries from the `movies` table. When the user clicks the `.add-to-watchlist` button, the movie is to be added to the user's list. I have a two separate tables `users` for users and `watchlist` for the junction table between `users` and `movies`.

My question is, how do I implement a function so that I can add the "specific" movie from the list of four to the user's list? For fetching the `movieId` I echoed that into a hidden input field, but still can't get that to work.

My jQuery code is:

```
$('.add-to-watchlist').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).parent().find('.watchlist-movie-id').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'includes/watchlist.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: data,
        success: function() {
            $(this).hide();
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
});
```

And `watchlist.php` is:

```
<?php 
require('includes/config.php');
require('includes/auth.php');
$defaultId = 'DEFAULT';
$currentDate = 'now()';
$movieId = $_POST['watchlist-movie-id'];
$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO watchlist (id, date, userId, movieId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssii", $defaultId, $currentDate, $currentUser, $movieId);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
?>
```

Comment: Side note: `$currentDate = 'now()';` why don't you just pass it in the query directly instead? is there a reason in particular as to why you're doing that?

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: where is `$currentUser` assigned?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, there's no particular reason as to why I assigned a variable for now(), thought having all variables like that looked cleaner in the query. As for the $currentUser, it comes from auth.php which holds the userId for the current user.

Comment: When you inspect the DOM, do the movie id's appear in your div attributes? If this is the case, are you receiving the id's on the server when you send away the ajax request? If you can debug this we'd be able to offer more help. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue I see is that your AJAX `data` field needs to be an object, otherwise the `$_POST` value will only contain a key with the value submitted.

```
var data = 'hi';

$.ajax({
   data: data
});
```

```
var_dump($_POST);

array(1) {
  ["hi"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

You should update your code to something like this, to get your expected result.

```
var movieId = $(this).parent().find('.watchlist-movie-id').val();

 $.ajax({
     //...
     data: {
        'watchlist-movie-id': movieId,
     },
     //...
  });
```

Otherwise you can submit the entire form using:

```
$.ajax({
   //...
    data: $(this).parent().serialize(),
   //...
});
```

I also suggest removing the hidden form field element and just use a `<button>` element instead, to make your life simpler.

```
<button type="submit" name="watchlist-movie-id" value="<?php echo $movieId; ?>">Add to Watchlist</button>
```

Then you can update your javascript to.

```
$('button[name="watchlist-movie-id"]').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var movieId = $(this).val();
     $.ajax({
       //...
        data: {
          'watchlist-movie-id': movieId,
       },
       success: function() {
             $(this).hide();
       },
       //...
    });
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much!